# Can't receive data from recvfrom() function?

Tags: c++, c, udp, winsock

Hello I would like to try to retrieve data from a source that sends data via UDP protocol with an address and a port. So, I have taken a program in C to retrieve data via port 3000 but I am not retrieving any data as the program is stuck on the `recvfrom()` function.

So, I checked if the source is sending data via the resource monitor. So, it does send data (send 400B/s). I also have no error when connecting to the corresponding port.

Here is the c code below:

```
#include <winsock2.h> // pour les fonctions socket
#include <cstdio> // Pour les Sprintf

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")


WSADATA initialisation_win32; 
int erreur;
int tempo; 
int nombre_de_caractere; 
char buffer[65535]; 
SOCKET id_de_la_socket; 
SOCKADDR_IN information_sur_la_source; 

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    printf("\nEcoute du port 3000\n");

    erreur=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&initialisation_win32);
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\nDesole, je ne peux pas initialiser Winsock du a l'erreur : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nWSAStartup  : OK");

    id_de_la_socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if (id_de_la_socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
        printf("\nDesole, je ne peux pas creer la socket du a l'erreur : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nsocket      : OK");

    information_sur_la_source.sin_family=AF_INET; 
    information_sur_la_source.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    information_sur_la_source.sin_port=htons(3000); // Ecoute sur le port 3000
    erreur=bind(id_de_la_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&information_sur_la_source,sizeof(information_sur_la_source));
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\nDesole, je ne peux pas ecouter ce port, code d'erreur : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nbind        : OK");

    tempo=sizeof(information_sur_la_source); 
    printf("\nbefore recvfrom");
    nombre_de_caractere=recvfrom(id_de_la_socket,buffer,1024,0,(struct sockaddr*)&information_sur_la_source,&tempo);
    printf("\nafter recvfrom");
    buffer[nombre_de_caractere]=0; 
    printf("\nVoici les donnees : %s",buffer);

    erreur=closesocket(id_de_la_socket);
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\nDesole, je ne peux pas liberer la socket du a l'erreur : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nclosesocket : OK");

    erreur=WSACleanup(); 
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\nDesole, je ne peux pas liberer winsock du a l'erreur : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nWSACleanup  : OK");
    }
```

Regards,

Comment: Did you disable any firewall blocking? Have you run Wireshark on the client?

Comment: I did not run wireshark on the client.

Comment: The firewall for public networks is disabled and the firewall for private networks is enabled. Do I need to disable the firewall for private networks?

Comment: Oh. So this is a computer you don't care about :-)

Comment: This is fortunately not my computer, it is only used for prototyping some software.

Comment: What does your client code look like? What IP address is it trying to send to? Is that IP address assigned to the server machine? Are the client and server 1) running on the same machine, 2) running on different machines on the same LAN, or 3) running on different machines on different networks/across the Internet?  It makes a big difference.

Comment: I have a sender program that can only be adjusted by an interface (ip,port and frequency) and is located on the same machine as the client program. I managed to receive data through my client code by changing the port but I can't receive any more since.

Comment: I also looked at the network via wireshark, and the sending program is sending the data via UDP to the correct port and IP address.

Comment: *Sorry I switched between clients and servers.